# Books and literature for implementing a language on the CLR

Tags: c#, .net, programming-languages, clr

I'm looking for books and literature on the inner workings of the CLR (and/or possibly the DLR), my long time goal is to implement a simple language on the CLR.

Answer (score 4):

A few starters for the CLR:

- [CLR via C#](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735621632) (soon to have an update for v4) (Jeff Richter)
- [ECMA 335](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-335.htm)
- [Essential .NET volume 1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201734117) (Don Box et al) - doesn't cover .NET 2.0, but a good starting point

The DLR itself is [Open Source](http://dlr.codeplex.com/), and its [documentation](http://dlr.codeplex.com/Wiki/View.aspx?title=Docs%20and%20specs) is pretty handy.

Comment: CLR via c# is very very good.

Answer (score 2):

I would imagine the source code for [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page) might have something to say about that.  The C# compiler is itself written in C#, and source code is available.

Answer (score 2):

[Irony - .NET Language Implementation Kit.](http://www.codeplex.com/irony)

Answer (score 1):

IronPython and IronRuby are open source implementations on top of the DLR (itself open sourced [on Codeplex](http://dlr.codeplex.com/)); and some IronPython releases included a ToyScript language which was meant to serve as an example for general DLR language implementation -- it may still be part of the DLR bundle these days.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the DLR, but here's some open source .NET languages that you can look at the source code for to see how they do it:

- [Boo](http://boo.codehaus.org/) - A Python-like language
- [LOLCode](http://lolcode.com/) - Pretty much a joke, but it could still provide some info for you

I'll post more if I can remember any others...

Answer (score 0):

[Expert .NET 2.0 IL Assembler](http://www.apress.com/book/view/1590596463) could also be useful as it describes a lot of the details for .NET applications.