# Creating a language interpreter

Tags: programming-languages

I am trying to understand how a language interpreter works. Can you guys point me the general lines on how an interpreter works?

I mean, suppose I have some lines written like this

```
10  x = 200;
20  for r = x to 1000 step 1
25  z = r + 32;
30  print z;
40  next r;
50  end;
```

what's the best way to build an interpreter that could run something like that?

Having a large matrix containing all functions allowed and searching for a match? The first line, for example: it is assigning 200 to a variable x, but these are symbols that does not exist.

If you guys can give me the direction...

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Writing an interpreter (or a compiler) for that sake is something that's really complicated. I'm no expert on the subject but in my university they have a course that's named compiler-technique and several of my friends attend to that course. If I remember correctly it consists of 4 steps, first was writing some code-patterns out (like you already have), then they use a program to look at it and find patterns and they build tokens that can be used to construct a tree out of the code. Then they build the compiler. As said I don't know much about it, but I've been told that it's not easy at all.

Comment: thanks.. that's the point. I am trying to get a general idea.

Comment: The canonical question for compiler and interpreter resources is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669/learning-to-write-a-compiler. And there are some resources listed there (like the Crenshaw tutorial) which  are pitched at a very simple level.

Comment: Many duplicates, some are in the Related panel to the right; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669/, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/256629/, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/294852/, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1255820/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compiler creation is a complex topic (an interpreter can be seen as a special compiler).

You have to first parse it - try to understand the syntax and then create some internal representation (abstract syntax tree) and then create some execution logic.

[Wikpedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler_construction) suggests http://mcs.une.edu.au/~comp319/

Comment: An AST is certainly the way to go for a full service compiler or interpreter, but it is *not* required.

Comment: right an AST isn't needed but some understanding is needed ... at least for the current line/statement.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old thread but most of the related questions are marked as duplicate or closed. So, here are my two cents.

I am surprised no one has mentioned [xtext](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xtext) yet. It is available as [Eclipse plugin](https://eclipse.org/Xtext/index.html) and [IntelliJ plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8074-xtext). It provides not just the parser like ANTLR but the whole pipeline (including parser, linker, typechecker, compiler) needed for a DSL. You can check it's source code on Github for understanding how, an interpreter/compiler works.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are talking about creating a DSL.
You might find this helpful (if you are ok with spending $$)

http://gilesbowkett.blogspot.com/2010/03/create-your-own-programming-language.html

Answer (score 1):

Learn about tools such as [lex/flex](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/) and [yacc/bison](http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/). These are most popular tools for building compilers in open software world. Many well known open source programs are written using them (including PHP, gcc, doxygen). You'll find a lot of free books and tutorials. They not only show how to use lex and yacc tools, but also explain general ideas behind compilers.

Comment: Don't forget ANTLR (http://www.antlr.org/) a tat more sophisticated than lex or bison but quite relevant.

Comment: Yes ANTLR is worth mentioning.

Comment: I think lex/yacc is much easier for a beginner.
Plus, shift-reduce parsing is a little easier to understand.

The OP wants to learn, so maybe lex/yacc is much better for that purpose; I have used both and find that lex/yacc is much better as a beginner.

Answer (score 1):

I'm interested in learning more about this as well. I found Douglas Crockford's [JavaScript parser](http://javascript.crockford.com/tdop/tdop.html) interesting, though from what I understand he's using a different method than is typical for parsing languages. It's not the full picture for interpreting and compiling, but I found it helpful to see some actual parsing implementation and the resulting restructuring of the code.

Answer (score 1):

you can find an open source 'Gold Parsing System' at http://goldparser.org. :)

there are some explained concepts on their site too where you can learn some rudimentary basics of the process.